# Hover в рейтинге

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте. *Простите за название реквеста, никак не смог сформулировать название.*

Нужно реализовать текстовый рейтинг (без картинок). Проблема заключается в `hover`'e. Нужно чтобы при наведении на 3 ссылку псевдокласс hover срабатывал на первую, вторую и третью ссылки.

`JavaScript` знаю плохо, можно сказать не знаю вообще. Так что был бы рад готовым библиотекам или ссылкам на статьи, где объясняется как это можно реализовать. (Второе предпочтительнее).

Большое спасибо.

Comment: [Это для раздумий](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2EBN/). Если по логике верстка подойдет (что навряд ли), то можно так сделать.

Но лучше, конечно, для этого применить JS.

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что нужно!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bHNPN/

Comment: Ааа, вот что подразумевалось под рейтингом.

«Мы угоняем его машину! Теперь понял.»

Шикарное использование RTL, хотя [можно еще проще](http://jsfiddle.net/bHNPN/5/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекомендую [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). Эта библиотека сильно облегчит вам жизнь (сравните реализацию вашей задачи на [JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/RNrSE/) и на [чистом JS](http://jsfiddle.net/9LLwC/)). Статьи приводить не буду, в Интернете их куча, да и в [официальной документации](http://api.jquery.com/) достаточно примеров. Только вот вам совет: старайтесь не зацикливаться на JQuery, обязательно изучите чистый JS.